# Error with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Consider the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
s0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{A''[t] - \[Omega]^2 A[t] == 1, A[0] == 0,
    A[1] == 0}, A, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Omega]}]
A1[\[Omega]_?NumericQ][t] := s0[\[Omega]][t];

s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{B''[t] - \[Omega]^2 B[t] == 
    D[A1[\[Omega]][t], t], B[0] == 0, B[1] == 0}, 
  B, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Omega]}]
B1[\[Omega]_?NumericQ][t] := s1[\[Omega]][t];

Plot[B1[1][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I get the error `"Dependent variables {B,A1[\[Omega]]} cannot depend on parameters {\ \[Omega]}"`.

How do I get rid of this error? In the second equation `A1` should be a known function, not a dependent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
s0 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{A''[t] - \[Omega]^2 A[t] == 1, A[0] == 0,
     A[1] == 0}, A, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Omega]}];
s1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{B''[t] - \[Omega]^2 B[t] == 
     D[s0[\[Omega]][t], t], B[0] == 0, B[1] == 0}, 
   B, {t, 0, 1}, {\[Omega]}];

Plot[s1[1][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! It works.... but why? Why defining the function `A` gave the error?

Comment: You defined them a bit wrong. You might have defined as `A1[\[Omega]_, t_] := s0[\[Omega]][t];  B1[\[Omega]_, t_] := s1[\[Omega]][t];` and call the plot as `Plot[B1[1, t], {t, 0, 1}]`. This will give the same effect. But this is not necessaty, since s0 and s1 are defined as standard functions and you may use them for plotting in a standard way.